# Добавление сцен или объектов из 3D MAX в FireMonkey

Tags: delphi, c++, 3d

Можно ли и как добавить сцены или просто объекты из 3D MAX в firemonkey? Нужно, чтобы объекты из 3D max загружались в Delphi C++ XE2 firemonkey.

Answer (score 1):

1. Распарсить файл 3DS (хотя бы вершины, полигоны и нормали). Задача посильная даже для одного человека. [Спецификация открытая](http://www.martinreddy.net/gfx/3d/3DS.spec)
2. Написать простейший визуализатор ([перспективная проекция](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection), [матричные преобразования](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix), один источник света, заливка  [плоская](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_shading#Flat_shading)/[по Гуро](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gouraud_shading)/[по Фонгу](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phong_reflection_model) - на что сил хватит, Z-сортировка полигонов) - уровень второго курса.
3. Нарисовать все это на `Canvas`.

---

**UPD0.** Вот это поворот, в XE, оказывается, есть средства для построения 3D приложений ). Тогда возможно вам поможет [официальное руководство](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/41874#6LoadingCOLLADA) по загрузке сцен в формате COLLADA.

Comment: а какова процедура открытия уже готовой сцены или элементов ее в делфи с помощью firemonkey.

Comment: да я знаю что там есть, но то что там есть как бы мало этих возможностей, да и надо разьиратся как из этого что есть строить свои сцены